# Why does a RavenDb session indicate changes have been made after only a query?

Tags: ravendb

```
var hasChanges0 = db.Advanced.HasChanges;                        //false
var checkinsTest = db.Query<Checkin>().ToList();
var hasChanges1 = db.Advanced.HasChanges;                        //true
var entityHasChanged = db.Advanced.HasChanged(checkinsTest[0]);  //true
```

When the above code segment is executed `hasChanges0` is `false`, but `hasChanges1` and `entityHasChanged`both are `true`.  Why is that the case since only a query has been executed and the entities have not been modified?

Comment: is there any property/field that is modified upon deserialization or that produces a unique output - like a getter only field that returns current date for example?

Comment: There a number of getter only properties on the entity.  Will this cause RavenDb to think the entity has been modified?  If so, is there any way around this?

Comment: I'm not into changeset generation - but it may be related to this. If any of these properties change each time you load the element / get the property value, it's also a valid change

Answer (score 1):

I've run across a few situations that would explain the behavior. I'm not sure which if any would fit.

**The data is changed as it is deserialized.** This can happen when your model has changed, e.g. a property added or removed. If the model adds a new string property, the data would deserialize into the model just fine, but the next time it is serialized, the json would be different.

**Metadata is added.** I have seen meta-data added to raven if the object was 'missing' some metadata. You can see that if you add an object to Raven through the HTTP API or raven studio, but don't add the meta-data for the type. There was also a bug fixed recently where the query relevance score was added to the metadata.

**Getter side effects** Like Daniel mentioned in his comments, if your getters have side effects or don't return the same value each time, that could cause problems, those should be moved to functions.

Probably the easiest way to figure out what is going on would be to let it save the object back, then compare the data AND meta-data from before and after.

Hope that helps.